# How can I guarantee near values ranges of chunks to be in the same shard?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Given the [example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/view-sharded-cluster-configuration/) of range partitioning from the official site of the MongoDB,
we see that the sharding key is based on the *zip* field. However, having a look at the cluster details, we notice that shard0001 contains two chunks of ranges [1,56000) and [57500,58140).
Wouldn't we expect from the intermediate ranges [56000,56800),[56800,57088) and [57088,57500) to be stored also on the shard0001?

When hearing about range partitioning, I am expecting that every shard should contain continuous shard keys.

Comment: Given that you can move chunks manually, then no, there's no such guarantee. Most you can expect is that all documents in a chunk are on the same shard.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev So how chunks are assigned to the shards when using range paritioning? Maybe randomly?

Comment: _webscale magic_ ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. It's been a while since I looked at it, so no idea what does it do now. In any case, it looks like an implementation detail. Why are you at all concerned about chunk distribution?

Comment: I am concerned about chunk distribution because i want to achieve some kind of locality for near index values.